# session_reset() not working properly

Tags: php, function, session, reset

According to descriptions of PHP.net , session_reset() should re-initialize session array with original values.Nevertheless when I run the following code the output will be "Some New Value" whereas the output should be "Some value".Also my mounted PHP version is 5.6.1.Please answer if you know what is the problem ?

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["A"] = "Some Value";

   echo $_SESSION["A"];

   $_SESSION["A"] = "Some New Value";  

  session_reset(); 

   echo $_SESSION["A"];

?>
```

Comment: What does the apache error file say?

Comment: What is the output of session  A?

Comment: Which one do you mean first session A or second one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_reset()` actually reverts `$_SESSION` to the point right after the `session_start()`, or more accurately, to the last values that were saved (either by script ending or `session_write_close`).

So if nothing was set for $_SESSION["A"] when the session was last closed, for your second `echo` you'll get `Notice: Undefined index: A`, however if you've had a value previously assigned to it (for example the value "Some New Value" is assigned and then saved) - you'll get that value. That's probably the case in your example.

Comment: Thanks . But why php.net says that the output should be "Some value" in that code ?

Comment: It doesn't say so. It says "reinitializes a session with original values stored in session storage." = meaning restoring the session to the last **stored state**. The session is stored either when your script ends or by explicit calling to `session_write_close()`.

Comment: Thank for your information. You are right , I understood it wrongly .